# Create parent entity and children and redirect request in fluent vapor

Tags: fluent, vapor

I´m trying to create an entity Task and one children using the same request object

```
func create(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<Response> {
    return try req.content.decode(Task.TaskForm.self).flatMap { taskForm in
        let user = try req.requireAuthenticated(User.self)
        let task = Task(name: taskForm.name, userId: user.id!)
        return task.save(on: req).map { t in
            let interval = try Interval(taskId: t.requireID())
            let t = interval.save(on: req)
            return t.save(on: req).map { _ in
                return req.redirect(to: "/dashboard")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error that I'm getting is this one:

Cannot convert return expression of type 'EventLoopFuture' to return type 'Response'.

Any ideas on what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work

```swift
func create(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<Response> {
    return try req.content.decode(Task.TaskForm.self).flatMap { taskForm in
        let user = try req.requireAuthenticated(User.self)
        let task = Task(name: taskForm.name, userId: user.id!)
        return task.create(on: req).flatMap { t in
            let interval = try Interval(taskId: t.requireID())
            return interval.create(on: req).flatMap { _ in
                return t.create(on: req).transform(to: req.redirect(to: "/dashboard"))
                // or your previous variant
//                return t.create(on: req).map { _ in
//                    return req.redirect(to: "/dashboard")
//                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are a few things you could learn

1. use `map` when you have to return non-future result
2. use `flatMap` you have to return `Future<>` result
3. use `create` instead of `save` when you are creating object in the db
4. don't leave future calls without handling them like you do on line #7